# In Windows8 App-Sqlite safely using string values with LIKE?

Tags: c#, sqlite, select, windows-8, sql-like

I tried this command:

```
List<Person> find_person = database.Query<Person>("Select * from Person where person_name like '%"+textbox.tex+'%" or person_surname like '%"+textbox.tex+'%"   ");
```

But this way is not safe as you know. Is there any way to execute this command?

Ex: In insert operation i can do it like ;

```
Person person = new Person();
```

and i will set the all of the value and use the `connection.InsertAsync(person);`

Is there any function for my select and like command?

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple Where query on your table:

```
SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("people");var query = conn.Table<Person>().Where(x => x.Name == "Matteo");
var result = await query.ToListAsync();
foreach (var item in result)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1} {2}", item.Id, item.Name, item.Surname));
}
```

Read more here: http://wp.qmatteoq.com/using-sqlite-in-your-windows-8-metro-style-applications/